# receiving invalid i/o for valid input in zodiac determiner

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement

I'm a beginner coder and i'm working on a project that determines horoscope.

**The problem**: The "**else if**" dates accurately determine horoscope based on the month and date entered by user but for the "**if**" statements for example May Gemini dates. I get invalid input for any dates entered between May 21 - May 31. I've tried rewriting the case but there's still a problem.

If anyone can see something that I don't and let me know, I'd be extremely grateful. Thanks!

```
switch (month) {

    case 1:
        if (month == 12 && day >= 22 && day <= 31)
            zodiac = "Capricorn";
        else if (month == 01 && day < 20)
            zodiac = "Capricorn";
        else
            zodiac = "Invalid Input";
        break;
    case 2:
        if (month == 1 && day >= 20 && day < 32)
            zodiac = "Aquarius";
        else if (month == 2 && day < 19)
            zodiac = "Aquarius";
        else
            zodiac = "Invalid Input";
        break;
    case 3:
        if (month == 2 && day >= 19 && day <= 29)
            zodiac = "Pisces";
        else if (month == 3 && day < 21)
            zodiac = "Pisces";
        else
            zodiac = "Invalid Input";
        break;
    case 4:
        if (month == 3 && day >= 21 && day < 32)
            zodiac = "Aries";
        else if (month == 4 && day < 20)
            zodiac = "Aries";
        else
            zodiac = "Invalid Input";
        break;
    case 5:
        if (month == 4 && day >= 20 && day < 31)
            zodiac = "Taurus";
        else if (month == 5 && day < 21)
            zodiac = "Taurus";
        else
            zodiac = "Invalid Input";
        break;
    case 6:
        if (month == 5 && day >= 21 && day < 32)
            zodiac = "Gemini";
        else if (month == 6 && day < 21)
            zodiac = "Gemini";
        else
            zodiac = "Invalid Input";
        break;
    case 7:
        if (month == 6 && day >= 21 && day < 31)
            zodiac = "Cancer";
        else if (month == 7 && day < 23)
            zodiac = "Cancer";
        else
            zodiac = "Invalid Input";
        break;
    case 8:
        if (month == 7 && day >= 23 && day < 32)
            zodiac = "Leo";
        else if (month == 8 && day < 23)
            zodiac = "Leo";
        else
            zodiac = "Invalid Input";
        break;
    case 9:
        if (month == 8 && day >= 23 && day < 32)
            zodiac = "Virgo";
        else if (month == 9 && day < 23)
            zodiac = "Virgo";
        else
            zodiac = "Invalid Input";
        break;
    case 10:
        if (month == 9 && day >= 23 && day < 31)
            zodiac = "Libra";
        else if (month == 10 && day < 23)
            zodiac = "Libra";
        else
            zodiac = "Invalid Input";
        break;
    case 11:
        if (month == 10 && day >= 23 && day < 32)
            zodiac = "Scorpio";
        else if (month == 11 && day < 22)
            zodiac = "Scorpio";
        else
            zodiac = "Invalid Input";
        break;
    case 12:
        if (month == 11 && day >= 22 && day < 31)
            zodiac = "Sagittarius";
        else if (month == 12 && day < 22)
            zodiac = "Sagittarius";
        else
            zodiac = "Invalid Input";
        break;
```

Comment: Are you sure that is the only place where you don't get the expected output? I would expect a few more `"Invalid Input"`s

Comment: I did a few at random and i didn't but actually i'm doubling back through them now and i have found more.

Comment: Within your switch-statement the month will always be equal to the case. So  checks like this: `case 1: if (month == 12)` will always fail

Comment: oh i see, so instead i should put for example both aquarius and capricorn in the first month because they both fall half in january. Instead of trying to put 2 months in one case, I should put 2 signs in a case because there are usually 2 signs assigned to a month. Thanks!

Comment: Indeed, see what I did in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your switch-statement the check for the month is already done with the cases you set. In case 1, the month is 1, etc...

I'd suggest you to rewrite the logic in your switch-statement to something like this:

```
switch (month) {

case 1: // --> month == 1 here
    if (day < 20) {
        zodiac = "Capricorn";
    } else if (day >= 20 && day <=31) {
        zodiac = "Aquarius";
    }
case 2: // --> month == 2 here
    if (day < 19) {
        zodiac = "Aquarius";
    } else if (day >= 19 && day <= 29)
        zodiac = "Pisces";
    break;

    // etc 
}
```